# how to compare and select the minimum of two features in R?

Tags: r

Assume i have the following dataset:

```
dt<-data.frame(X=sample(5),Y=sample(5))
```

now, i need to compare these two features and select the one which is smaller.

```
  X Y
1 4 3
2 5 2
3 2 4
4 3 5
5 1 1
```

Then the expected answer would be

```
3
2
2
3
1
```

I know

```
min(dt[1,])
```

could be helpful but it only gives me 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pmin`, which is the vectorized version of min:

```
pmin(dt$X,dt$Y)
```

Like thus:

```
> dt<-data.frame(X=sample(5),Y=sample(5))
> dt
  X Y
1 3 2
2 4 3
3 1 5
4 2 4
5 5 1
> pmin(dt$X,dt$Y)
[1] 2 3 1 2 1
```

Comment: it gives me `integer(0)`

Comment: That wouldn't be the result you would get if your `dt` is defined by `dt<-data.frame(X=sample(5),Y=sample(5))`

Answer (score 0):

```
high <- apply(dt[,c("X","Y")], 1, max)
```

is another implementation

`integer(0)` or length 0 element happens when one of X or Y is of length(0)

> For min or max, a length-one vector. For pmin or pmax, a vector of length the longest of the input vectors, or length zero if one of the inputs had zero length.

(from documentation)

`max(which(1:3 == 5),10)` works but `pmax(which(1:3 == 5),10)` gives `integer(0)`